# Optimization of pandas replace

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I am working with a large [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) object of `shape (4879301, 214)`. I am trying to accomplish:

- Loop through a specified list of columns from the dataframe
- For all values in that dataframe, if a value appears 10% or less of the time, change it to `"column_Other"`

I have accomplished this with the following code:

```
thresh = int(df[col].shape[0]*0.10)
for col in col_list:
  for val in df[col].unique():
    if df.loc[df[col]==val].shape[0] <= thresh:
      df[col].replace(val, '{}_Other'.format(col), inplace=True)
```

However, this has been running for hours and we are barely processed, since some columns have ~50K unique values. Is there anyway to optimize this?

Comment: could you provide reproducible example? Fake data but with similar distribution of values

Comment: How much data would be necessary to replicate or test this? I didn't include any given the size of my current set.

Comment: Don't include data, just make simple data generator

Comment: I still need to specify the amount of data produced by a generator.

Comment: And it would be size of your dataframe. If it result too large for my RAM, I will diminish it. To be sure we understand each other - by "data generator" I mean piece of code that will help me fast generate fake data on my machine (without need to download anything)

Comment: I'm familiar with what data generation is. It's probably not worth the investment for me to distribution test ~50K samples for a single column, though I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with the parameter `normalize=True`, then keep the index of the result where the percentage is below your threshold. Use `loc` and `isin` to replace the wanted values. The interest is that you replace all the values present in your columns less than the threshold at once, not each one with a different `replace` operation

```
# dummy data
np.random.seed(10)

n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({
    0:np.random.choice(list('abcd'), size=n, p=[0.32,0.32,0.32,0.04]),
    1:np.random.choice(list('efghi'), size=n, p=[0.32,0.32,0.23,0.08, 0.05]),
    2:np.random.choice(list('jkl'), size=n, p=[0.33,0.33,0.34])
})
print(df.head())
#    0  1  2
# 0  c  f  l
# 1  a  g  l
# 2  b  e  k
# 3  c  f  l
# 4  b  g  k
```

Solution using a simple loop for

```
col_list = [0,1,2]
thresh = 0.10
for col in col_list:
    s = df[col].value_counts(normalize=True)
    print(s.index[s<0.1]) # to remove once sure of the result
    df.loc[df[col].isin(s.index[s<thresh]), col] = '{}_Other'.format(col)

# result of the print
# Index(['d'], dtype='object')
# Index(['h', 'i'], dtype='object')
# Index([], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Significantly faster. Thank you. I didn't know `value_counts()` had a `normalize` (or `bin`) parameter!

Comment: @wundermahn I realized that with the dummy data I created, it is hard to see the time difference, but in the extreme case of all values are different in the column, like with `df = pd.DataFrame({0:range(1000)})` I get a speed up of x1000 with value_counts

Comment: Using this seems to replace the _column name_, but not the values in the column, how can I replace the values in the column?

Comment: @wundermahn hmm no, this code does not change column name at all. the only assignation is this line `df.loc[df[col].isin(s.index[s<thresh]), col] = '{}_Other'.format(col)` and I'm sure it changes values in the column `col` for the rows selected by `df[col].isin(s.index[s<thresh])`.  there is nowehere the column name itself is affected

Comment: My mistake, thanks @ Ben.T~